# Ubuntu Studio 14: Suddenly no sound from jack

Tags: 14.04, sound, jack

My home studio setup was performing fine, when something crashed the jackdbus. I rebooted the computer, and now I can't hear anything from my system outputs.

Capturing still works fine, and playback metering indicates that a signal is being sent to the outputs. I just can't hear anything.

I tried it from the live cd environment, where things still work as expected. Oh, and this all started sometime after I installed virtualbox and the Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Go on system monitor. Find the process named "jackd" end it. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

My sound was not working or choppy. I'm running VirtualBox with Windows 7 host, and Ubuntu Studio as a guest. I tried lots of stuff, but only this fixed it for me:
I ran **QjackCtl**, clicked **Setup**, then under the **Settings tab**, I change the Frames/Period from 1024 to **2048**, and everything started working.
If you have this problem, I suggest trying 2048, and if that doesn't fix it, try some other rates in Frames/Period (it only has 9 suggested settings).